Why can't I get C# script to work in unity?
I'm starting with unity and just wrote code for resume menu, but I have no idea how to make it so it works.
This is the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResumeMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pauseMenu;

    public bool isPaused;

    void Start()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (isPaused)
            {
                ResumeGame();
            }
            else
            {
                PauseGame();
            }
        }
    }

    public void PauseGame()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        isPaused = true;
    }

    public void ResumeGame()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        isPaused = false;
    }
}

this is how the game looks rn
I have no idea where to put the script so the menu works only in game. I tried looking at some videos and most use some game manager

There is no problem with your code.
Create an empty object in your scene and insert your script there. And if you hook up "pauseMenu" to your script it should work fine.
If you want to make it work as a button, you can also connect the code below to the button.


I really like indie games, so I hope you don't give up and make great games.
